# Very Basic Matlab Plot

Tags: matlab

So, I want to plot some points like this (sorry for my pathetic drawing):

[image]

So, simply I have some points for the corresponding numbers in x, and I want to plot them based on their values on Y-axis.

I also need to connect the mean of each column (the Y indices) with a straight line, like viz.

[image]

**Edit:** This means say the column with X index 5 has average of 5.6, 10 has 4.5 etc. I want a curve to connect average values of each column. The blue line is connecting the averages of each column.

I wrote a code that fails with the following error:

```
Error using scatter (line 62)
X and Y must be vectors of the same length.
```

Here is the code:

```
x = [5,10,15,20];
scatter(4, data_tab.Bitsi);
hold on
scatter(8, data_tab.Bitsa);
scatter(12, data_tab.Bitsb);
scatter(16, data_tab.Bitsc);
scatter(20, data_tab.Bitsd);
```

Each of the columns for `5, 10 ...` has 4 values as well.
How do I do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: What does this statement mean? "I also want to connect the mean of each column (the Y indices) with a straight line"?

Comment: "I wrote a code that fails:" How? Provide error messages in full or describe what's wrong so we're not left guessing.

Comment: edited. sorry for misinformation.

Comment: @horchler added data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution but it plots what you want

```
a = rand(1,4);
mean_a = mean(a);
b = rand(1,4);
mean_b = mean(b);
c = rand(1,4);
mean_c = mean(c);
d = rand(1,4);
mean_d = mean(d);
e = rand(1,4);
mean_e = mean(e);

means_array = [mean_a mean_b mean_c mean_d mean_e];


x = [5,10,15,20];
scatter([4 4 4 4], a);
hold on
scatter([8 8 8 8], b);
scatter([12 12 12 12], c);
scatter([16 16 16 16], d);
scatter([20 20 20 20], e);
plot([4 8 12 16 20], means_array);
```

The problem with your code was that you weren´t supplying the same number of elements in the x and y vectors of the scatter function